# Unanticipated Index Creation in MSSQL and its Impact on Column Alteration - INDEX_VV_<3to4DigitNumber>_<3to4DigitNumber>

Tags: sql-server, indexing, alter-table, alter

SQL Version - 12.00.6118(SQL Server 2014)

In MSSQL, indexes are created in a few tables and certain columns apart from the ones defined in the schema with the index name format *'INDEX_VV_<3to4DigitNumber>_<3to4DigitNumber>' (e.g., INDEX_VV_40627_40626)*.

Due to this, when attempting to ALTER the column, we face an issue as there is an unexpected index that is dependent on the column.

We have checked and confirmed whether there were any index rebuilding activities, SQL tuning performed, SQL jobs configured, or any custom modifications made at the SQL level in relation to indexes.

Is there any scenario in which an index with such a format will be created?

Comment: A user created them..? A User can create an index with what ever name they want. Or perhaps a process in (one of) your applications? That isn't the style name SQL Server uses when objects are created without names.

Comment: Automatic tuning in Azure SQL Database can create indexes automatically but not with that naming convention. And you say you are on premise anyway. Do you have any employees or software tools with initials VV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any scenario in which an index with such a format will be created?

No. SQL Server on prem doesn't do "[Automatic Index Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning?view=sql-server-ver16#automatic-index-management)".  Some user or third-party tool created those indexes.